# Retrieving list of virtual desktops assigned to remote user in Azure in C#

Tags: c#, azure, selenium-webdriver, remote-desktop

I'm working on a C# application that does a preliminary check of new hires' accounts to certain systems. One of the check required is to see if the account is given access to a shared virtual machine in Azure. I already have a solution via Selenium and the web-based URL provided here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/users/connect-web

If I run the app on the user's own machine, that works. However, I need to be able to run this tool against a list of users, so using just one machine that loops through each new hires' accounts and verify they all have access to the same VM using only one machine. Unfortunately, the tool will keep using the logged in user's credentials on the Azure URL even though I force logout and pass the other user's credentials, and setting the Selenium web driver to run the browser in In-Private or incognito mode doesn't work as it requires that the browser is opened using the user profile. So I'm wondering:

1. Is there an API that can pull the user's list of assigned resources by passing the user credentials? Or
2. In absence of which, is there a way to programmatically create a profile for the users in the host machine for use in Edge so it will login with the correct credentials instead of that of the logged in user?

To add, the host machine runs this tool in the same network as what the new hires will connect to, and we login to Azure typically just by passing the email registered in Azure AD.